# Textured object becomes black in Texture Paint mode?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

I've unlinked all object data, materials and textures. The texture is assigned and visible when I'm in Object mode and Edit mode. But when I switch over to Texture paint mode, I can't see the texture that I want and I have to start from scratch. Thanks for any help you can give me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do things change if you press `Alt`+`Z` while in Texture Paint mode ?

Comment: Yes, the original object loses it's texture, but the duplicate stays the same.

Comment: Do you mean "the same" that duplicate (as I understand the black one on the second image) remains being black ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.